# IIS Rewrite rules stripping .ASPX, but Google Analytics still showing

Tags: iis, google-analytics, url-rewriting

I've implemented IIS 7.0 rewrite rules for my site which strips out the .aspx extension, makes the URL lower case, and strips "default.aspx" to clean up the URL, and all of the rewrite rules work great.

However, in looking through my google analytics reports for a time period after the rules were put into production, under "Behavior", "Site Content", some of the entries still show the extension.  For example, it shows these pages being hit:

```
/about/
/about/default.aspx
```

There is no way the rule isn't working for /about/default.aspx, and I can go to that URL and it redirects to /about/

So what is going on here?  Analytics shouldn't know anything about default.aspx since all of those rules are done on the server before anything is returned to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  The GA Filters were set up to append "default.aspx" to any page which didn't have a page defined.

For example, if I went to
/about/

it would report as /about/default.aspx

But if I went to

/about/features

(features.aspx is a page)

it would not append it!

Answer (score 0):

If your site uses redirects, the redirecting page becomes the landing page's referrer. For example, if you've changed your site so that default.aspx now redirects to /, then root folder(/) becomes the referrer for default.aspx. If someone reached your site via a Google search that sent them first to default.aspx, you won't have any data regarding the Google search.

For this reason, you should place the Analytics tracking code on the redirecting page as well as on the landing page. This way, the redirecting page will capture the actual referrer information for your reports.

By doing this, you may get the analytics log only the redirected url.